# After deleting item 1 in the recyclerview when clicking on item 2 it doesn't show anything ( onClick opens Activity where there is a recyclerv items)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

So I'm trying to make an app where there is a button + and when clicking it , it shows an AlertDialog with a text "Workout Name:" and EditText with hint " Enter workout name ". When writing down the workout name and clicking the positive button " Add ", it adds an item to the recyclerview. There is onClick method for the items in the recyclerview and when clicking on a "Workout" it opens similar activity , but this time when clicking the " + " you are adding an exercise associated to this " Workout ". I've added some exercises and then created another "workout" and added different exercises to it, when deleting the first "workout" i want to delete only the exercises associated to it and to not touch the second one , unfortunatelly when i delete "Workout 1" it deletes the exercises in "Workout 2" aswell. I'm using SharedPreferences for saving the information and tried to use HashMap for the exercises , it's now day 2 and I really can't find the answer by myself.
This is the code of the first activity:

```
public class FitNotes extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkoutInterface {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Button btnAddWorkout;
TextView txtViewInstructions;
List<WorkoutItem> workoutList;
WorkoutAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

private static final String WORKOUT_LIST_KEY = "workoutList";

private Map<String, List<WorkoutExerciseItem>> exercisesMap;

private static final String EXERCISES_MAP_KEY = "EXERCISES_MAP"; // Define the key for exercisesMap


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fit_notes);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_workout);
    btnAddWorkout = findViewById(R.id.btnAddWorkout);
    txtViewInstructions = findViewById(R.id.txtViewInstructions);

    workoutList = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerViewAdapter = new WorkoutAdapter(this, workoutList, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new FitNotes.SwipeToDeleteCallback());
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    updateInstructionsVisibility();

    loadData();
    loadExercisesMap();
    btnAddWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddWorkoutDialog();
        }
    });
}
private void showAddWorkoutDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogBackground);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_workout, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText workoutNameEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_workout_name);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String workoutName = workoutNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            
            if (!workoutName.isEmpty()) {
                workoutList.add(new WorkoutItem(workoutName)); 
                Log.d("WorkoutList", "Workout added: " + workoutName);
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 


                exercisesMap.put(workoutName, new ArrayList<>());

                saveData();
                saveExercisesMap();

                updateInstructionsVisibility();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

            positiveButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); 
            negativeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


        }
    });
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

    dialog.show();
}

private class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    SwipeToDeleteCallback() {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        
        WorkoutItem deletedWorkout = workoutList.get(position);
        Log.d("SwipedWorkout", "Deleting workout: " + deletedWorkout.getName()); 

        workoutList.remove(position);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        deleteWorkout(deletedWorkout.getName());
        saveData();
        saveExercisesMap();
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, workoutList.size());
        updateInstructionsVisibility();
    }
}
public void deleteWorkout(String workoutName) {
    Iterator<WorkoutItem> iterator = workoutList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        WorkoutItem workoutItem = iterator.next();
        if (workoutItem.getName().equals(workoutName)) {
            iterator.remove();

            if (exercisesMap.containsKey(workoutName)) {
                exercisesMap.remove(workoutName); 
                Log.d("deleteWorkout", "Exercises removed for workout: " + workoutName);
            } else {
                Log.e("deleteWorkout", "No exercises found for workout: " + workoutName);
            }

            saveData();
            saveExercisesMap();
            updateInstructionsVisibility();
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(workoutList);

    editor.putString(WORKOUT_LIST_KEY, json);
    editor.apply();
    Log.d("SaveData", "WorkoutList saved to SharedPreferences: " + json);

}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(WORKOUT_LIST_KEY, "");

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<WorkoutItem>>(){}.getType();
    workoutList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (workoutList == null) {
        workoutList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    recyclerViewAdapter = new WorkoutAdapter(this, workoutList, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    updateInstructionsVisibility();
    Log.d("LoadData", "WorkoutList loaded from SharedPreferences: " + json);

}
private void updateInstructionsVisibility() {
    if (workoutList.isEmpty()) {
        txtViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Show textViewInstructions
    } else {
        txtViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide textViewInstructions
    }
}

private void loadExercisesMap() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(EXERCISES_MAP_KEY, "");

    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<WorkoutExerciseItem>>>(){}.getType();
    exercisesMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (exercisesMap == null) {
        exercisesMap = new HashMap<>();
    }
    Log.d("LoadExercisesMap", "ExercisesMap loaded from SharedPreferences: " + json);

}

private void saveExercisesMap() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(exercisesMap);

    editor.putString(EXERCISES_MAP_KEY, json);
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public void onWorkoutClick(int position) {
    if (position >= 0 && position < workoutList.size()) {
        String workoutName = workoutList.get(position).getName();

        // Handle the clicked workout
        if (exercisesMap.containsKey(workoutName)) {
            List<WorkoutExerciseItem> exercises = exercisesMap.get(workoutName);
            Log.d("WorkoutClick", "Exercises found for workout: " + workoutName + ", Exercise count: " + exercises.size());


            Intent intent = new Intent(FitNotes.this, Workout.class);
            intent.putExtra("WORKOUT_NAME", workoutName);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.e("FitNotes", "Workout not found in exercisesMap: " + workoutName);
        }
        } else {
        // Handle out-of-bounds index or other scenarios
        Log.e("FitNotes", "Invalid workout item clicked");
        }
     }
}
```

And this is my next Activity :

```
public class Workout extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnAddExercise;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<WorkoutExerciseItem> exerciseList;
TextView textViewWorkoutName, textViewInstructions;
WorkoutExerciseAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
Map<String, List<WorkoutExerciseItem>> exercisesMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

    btnAddExercise = findViewById(R.id.btnAddExercise);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_workoutExercise);
    textViewWorkoutName = findViewById(R.id.textView_workoutName);
    textViewInstructions = findViewById(R.id.textViewInstructions);

    String selectedWorkoutName = getIntent().getStringExtra("WORKOUT_NAME");

    textViewWorkoutName.setText(selectedWorkoutName);

    exerciseList = new ArrayList<>();


    exercisesMap = loadExercisesMap();
    exercisesMap = loadExercisesMap();

    if (exercisesMap == null) {
        exercisesMap = new HashMap<>();
    }


    exerciseList = exercisesMap.get(selectedWorkoutName);
    if (exerciseList == null) {
        exerciseList = new ArrayList<>();
        exercisesMap.put(selectedWorkoutName, exerciseList);
    }


    recyclerViewAdapter = new WorkoutExerciseAdapter(this, exerciseList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new Workout.SwipeToDeleteCallback());
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    updateInstructionsVisibility(exerciseList);
    loadExercisesMap();
    btnAddExercise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddExerciseDialog();
        }
    });
}
private void showAddExerciseDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogBackground);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_workout, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText exerciseNameEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_workout_name);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String exerciseName = exerciseNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!exerciseName.isEmpty()){

                exerciseList.add(new WorkoutExerciseItem(exerciseName)); 
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                saveExercisesMap(exercisesMap);
                updateInstructionsVisibility(exerciseList);

            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
           dialog.dismiss();
       }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

            positiveButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); 
            negativeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); 


        }
    });
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

    dialog.show();
}

private class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    SwipeToDeleteCallback() {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        exerciseList.remove(position);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        saveExercisesMap(exercisesMap);
        updateInstructionsVisibility(exerciseList);
    }
}

private void saveExercisesMap(Map<String, List<WorkoutExerciseItem>> exercisesMap) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(exercisesMap);

    editor.putString("EXERCISES_MAP", json);
    editor.apply();
}

private Map<String, List<WorkoutExerciseItem>> loadExercisesMap() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("EXERCISES_MAP", "");

    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<WorkoutExerciseItem>>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
private void updateInstructionsVisibility(List<WorkoutExerciseItem> exerciseList) {
    if (exerciseList.isEmpty()) {
        textViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        textViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use SQLite Database or ROOM Database to store those types of information. It helps to prevent crashes and you also add more cool features to it. It's very lightweight and easy to configure into an app.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: @MDEV thanks! I found the answer to my question , last few days i started exploring room database and did this without a problem ! :) Thanks for the suggestion i really appreciated it ! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked when i changed to ROOM database:

```
public class Workout extends AppCompatActivity implements ExerciseInterface {
Button btnAddExercise;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView textViewWorkoutName, textViewInstructions;
ExerciseAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout);

    btnAddExercise = findViewById(R.id.btnAddExercise);
    textViewWorkoutName = findViewById(R.id.textView_workoutName);
    textViewInstructions = findViewById(R.id.textViewInstructions);

    String selectedWorkoutName = getIntent().getStringExtra("WORKOUT_NAME");

    textViewWorkoutName.setText(selectedWorkoutName);

    btnAddExercise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddExerciseDialog();
        }
    });
    initRecyclerView();
    loadExerciseList();
    updateInstructionsVisibility();
    recyclerViewAdapter.setExerciseInterface(this);

}
@Override
public void onItemClick(ExerciseItem exerciseItem) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Workout.this, Exercise.class);
    intent.putExtra("EXERCISE_NAME", exerciseItem.getExerciseName()); // Pass workout details
    intent.putExtra("EXERCISE_ID", exerciseItem.getId());
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void showAddExerciseDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogBackground);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_exercise, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText exerciseNameEditText = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_exercise_name);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String exerciseName = exerciseNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!exerciseName.isEmpty()){
                int workoutId = getIntent().getIntExtra("WORKOUT_ID",-1);
                if (workoutId != -1) {
                saveNewExercise(exerciseName,workoutId);
                loadExerciseList();
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateInstructionsVisibility();
                } else {

                }
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

            positiveButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            negativeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


        }
    });
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

    dialog.show();
}
private void updateInstructionsVisibility() {
    if (recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
        textViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        textViewInstructions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
private void deleteItem(ExerciseItem exerciseItem) {

    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    database.exerciseDao().delete(exerciseItem);
    recyclerViewAdapter.removeExerciseItem(exerciseItem);

}
private void saveNewExercise(String exerciseName, int workoutId) {
    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    workoutId = getIntent().getIntExtra("WORKOUT_ID", -1);
    try {
    WorkoutItem workoutItem = database.workoutDao().getWorkoutById(workoutId);
        if (workoutItem != null) {
        // The workoutId exists, proceed with saving ExerciseItem
        ExerciseItem exerciseItem = new ExerciseItem();
        exerciseItem.exerciseName = exerciseName;
        exerciseItem.workoutId = workoutId;
        database.exerciseDao().insertExerciseItem(exerciseItem);
    } else {

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
public void initRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_exercise);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new ExerciseAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new Workout.SwipeToDeleteCallback());
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
private void loadExerciseList() {
    AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
    int selectedWorkoutId = getIntent().getIntExtra("WORKOUT_ID", -1);
    if (selectedWorkoutId != -1) {
        // Fetch exercises associated with the selected workout ID
        List<ExerciseItem> exercisesForWorkout = database.exerciseDao().getExercisesForWorkout(selectedWorkoutId);
        recyclerViewAdapter.setExerciseList(exercisesForWorkout);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        Log.e("WorkoutActivity", "No workout ID found in the intent");
    }
}
private class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    SwipeToDeleteCallback() {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        ExerciseItem deletedItem = recyclerViewAdapter.getExerciseList().get(position);
        deleteItem(deletedItem);
        updateInstructionsVisibility();
    }
}
```

}